# Authentication from Scratch in Production App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

Is it a good idea to use the [Authentication from scratch system](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#top) from Hart's Ruby on Rail's Tutorial in a production app?  Are there security issues with using it? Should an app that's already using it migrate to Devise instead? How would one do that?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, using a gem like `devise` is a better solution than writing authentication from scratch, since you might not even be aware about some security issues that such gems can handle for us, as they are developed by a whole community instead of a single person.

Moreover, I would really prefer not to reinvent the wheel, when I already have an awesome solution available. I have used `devise` in many production applications, and it does so much more than plain authentication, and that is where it shines :)

However, if you are learning your ways through ruby on rails, I would really recommend you to write the authentication from scratch, but even then, not for a production app, initially.

As it says in [devise's documentation](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/):

> If you are building your first Rails application, we recommend you to
>   not use Devise. Devise requires a good understanding of the Rails
>   Framework. In such cases, we advise you to start a simple
>   authentication system from scratch, today we have two resources:
>
> Michael Hartl's online book:
>   http://railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#top
>   Ryan Bates' Railscast:
>   http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch
>
> Once you have solidified your understanding of Rails and
>   authentication mechanisms, we assure you Devise will be very pleasant
>   to work with. :)

Comment: So let's say we followed that and now have an app in use with Hartl's authentication. What should we do now?